# PROC SQL case when?

Tags: sas

I want to combine the following two tables. The final table is similar like table B. Only change the name of anchor and readmit based on the anchor_num and readm_num.

if b.anchor_num=a.sprv_num then b.anchor_provider =a.sprv_full_name;
if b.readm_num =a.sprv_num then b.readmit_provider=a.sprv_full_name;

```
Table A
SPRV_NUM    SPRV_FULL_NAME
70010Q40    NFI MASSACHUSETTSINC
700122330   NORTHAMPTON VA MEDICAL CENTER
700122223   RADIUS SPECIALTY HOSPITAL LLCDBA
700122331   SHAUGHNESSY KAPLANREHAB HOSPINC
700122330   SPAULDING HOSPITALCAMBRIDGE INC
70010Q402   SPRING HILL RECOVERY CENTER INC
700122222   SPRINGFIELD PARK VIEW HOSPITALDBA
700122222   SPRINGFIELD PARK VIEW HOSPITALDBA
70010Q057   ST ANNES HOME INC
70010Q007   STAR OF RHODE ISLAND

Table B
anchor_num          anchor              readm_num         readmit
700122224   Harrington memorial hospital    700122229   first psychiatricap inc
700122224   Harrington memorial hospital    700122224   Harrington memorial hospital
700122330   NORTHAMPTON VA MEDICAL          700122223   RADIUS SPECIALTY HOSPITAL
700122222   SPRINGFIELD PARK VIEW           700122222   SPRINGFIELD PARK VIEW 
700122226   HENRY HEYWOOD  HOSPITAL         70010Q402   SPRING HILL RECOVERY INC
70010Q057   ST ANNES HOME INC               70010Q057   ST ANNES HOME INC
```

Thanks,
Jane

Answer (score 0):

First remove duplicate sprv_num from table a with proc sort:

```
proc sort data=tablea out=tablea2 nodupkey;
    by sprv_num;
run;
```

(The nodupkey function removes observations with duplicates of the variables you sort by.)

Then merge the tables:

```
proc sql;
    create table final as
    select b.anchor_num, coalesce(x.sprv_full_name, b.anchor) as anchor_provider, 
        b.readm_num, coalesce(y.sprv_full_name, b.readmit) as readmit_provider
    from tableb as b 
        left join tablea2 as x on b.anchor_num = x.sprv_num 
        left join tablea2 as y on b.readm_num = y.sprv_num
    order by anchor_num;
quit;
```

The coalesce function returns the first non-missing value. This means that if table a didn't have a value for a given anchor_num or readm_num, the name is taken from table b. I merge table a in twice because there are two different places where a name is needed.